# SSRS Subreport not seing values in only one dataset

Tags: dataset, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, subreports

I'm working on a series of reports which need to be shown in two languages so I've created a common header that I planned on embedding into the content of each report. I have two data sets, one that looks up a set of strings in English or French (depending on a parameter passed to the report), and another with numerical data.

The original header worked fine and when I extracted it into a separate report it also runs fine. I am just passing the name of the report to the subreport.  When I run the main report, it seems that the values in my string dataset are all null (I've tried all of them) yet if I try data from my numerical dataset, the fields have values and get displayed as the title.

If I also insert a text field with the same expression to display the report title after the subreport, it works fine but the title still does not get passed to the subreport.

I cannot make any sense of why this would be happening, anyone have a clue?

I'm using Report Builder 2.0 and SQL Server 2008.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I worked around this issue by simply passing my parameters on down to the subreports and letting them call the stored procs again. Not ideal since I now have to call that one stored proc 3 times but it probably won't be noticed.

I tried several other work arounds and received errors like rsAggregateInCalculatedFieldExpression, so my best guess is that this was caused by attempting to use an aggregate function (First) where it is not allowed but the error was never shown.